# gdb connecting target by default

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

When debugging on remote target by using gdbserver, at client normally I do

```
$ gdb <enter>
(gdb) target remote <IP>:<PORT>
```

Is there an option for gdb that I can do this by giving gdb a proper argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just something like: gdb -ex "target remote ..."